# If I described my name, I would do it like this

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

There's multiple parts to my name. In fact, I'd say there's two short and three long parts.

First is two, second is three. But they're the long ones.
Then things get a bit trickier, but no harder than a simple dot to dot.
My fourth is... Actually, on second thoughts, maybe that's too direct.
What I will say, though, is that this part ends in the same way this sentence does.

Are you with me so far? Take a deep breath, we're up to the last part.

This part's beginning is contained in "competition", but you'll only see it if you're meticulous.
The next is central to my most famous speech.
I will be kind-hearted and include the next bit directly in this line. Though it is not the letters you think.
And finally, we get to the point.

The question, of course, is: What is my name?

Comment: Thought I'd commented on this one before... FANTASTIC riddle. So much red-herring stuff, and yet everything fits nicely in the end.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The answer is:

> MORSE CODE

First is two, second is three. But they're the long ones.

> M is -- and O is --- in morse code (two and three long ones).

Then things get a bit trickier, but no harder than a simple dot to dot.

> R is .-. in morse code (dot to dot).

My fourth is... Actually, on second thoughts, maybe that's too direct.

> S is ...

What I will say, though, is that this part ends in the same way this sentence does.

> E is . (how the sentence ends)

Are you with me so far? Take a deep breath, we're up to the last part.

This part's beginning is contained in "competition", but you'll only see it if you're meticulous.

> C is -.-. which is hidden in "compe**titi**on".  The meticulous clue refers to dotting your i's and crossing your t's. (From Alconja in comments).

The next is central to my most famous speech.

> O is in the middle of SOS "most famous speech".

I will be kind-hearted and include the next bit directly in this line. Though it is not the letters you think.

> D is -.. hidden in "kind-hearted" "line." "think."

And finally, we get to the point.

> E is .

Comment: Well that was quicker than I expected. Well done. :) Though your logic for C wasn't what I intended. If you're meticulous with writing "competition", you'll be sure to cross your "t"s and dot your "i"s (-.-.). Also, not sure if you realised, but the "two short and three long parts" translates to "..--- parts", or "2 parts".